# Strapi CMS, Heroku error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: node.js, macos, heroku, strapi

Three months ago, I created an Strapi App that has deployed on Heroku, and everything works fine. I used macOS 10.13.6 and node 14.15.4 for the local environment

The configuration of database was created inside a file named database.js which located in rootApp/config/env/production/database.js
The following are everything config inside these file (database.js):

```
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
const config = parse(process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL);
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'postgres',
        host: "ec2-35-169-184-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        port: 5432,
        database: "d3d9tcukxxx",
        username: "mwtwuvkwxxxx",
        password: "42f0337xxxxx",
      },
      options: {
                ssl:true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

But after 3 months (right now), I checked from `heroku logs --tail` then these app getting an error and the message was:

> error error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.86.36.125", user "mwtwuvkwtrqpir", database "d3d9tcukrk5fgh", SSL off

I used Strapi 3.2.5 , and I was deployed on Heroku Postgres with Plan free (Hobby).
I hope everyone helping me for this questions, and hope helping others for same case.
Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We had the same issue on our Heroku instances and just recently found a fix.

Adding `rejectUnauthorized` to the database config appears to work.

`config/database.js`

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'postgres',
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost'),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 5432),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'strapi'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'strapi'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'strapi'),
        schema: env('DATABASE_SCHEMA', 'public'), // Not Required
        ssl: {
          rejectUnauthorized: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL_SELF', false), // For self-signed certificates
        },
      },
      options: {
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I cannot take full credit however, it was this post on the Strapi forum that led me to the answer:
https://forum.strapi.io/t/error-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-ssl-off/3409

subsequently this link:
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#database

Comment: that's great, man!, I also got the solve from those link: https://forum.strapi.io/t/error-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-ssl-off/3409 a few days ago, thank you

Comment: Did not work for Azure PostgreSQL server with disabled SSL. Strapi version 3.6.8

Comment: For Azure PostgreSQL, Strapi 4, I had to enable SSL, no SSL didn't work. I had to download the certificate from Networking tab (.pem file) and on strapi I added below env vars: DATABASE_SSL=true cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cert=/path/to/cert/cert-name.pem

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution here.